# How to hook into a change in the model in a widget

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to respond to a change in one of the properties of the model in a widget. To be clear, when the value of the property changes, I want to run some code to react to the change. In a parent widget I have a date picker which changes the date in the model.

I cannot get the custom setter to be called _setParentPropertyAttr...

If I include this in my widget

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output" data-dojo-props="value: at(rel:, 'ParentProperty')">
```

It works nicely. Changing the date picker outputs the current value to the page. So I can supply the value property to the output widget when the date changes in the model. But what I need to do (I think) is supply a custom property with the date property in the model when the date picker changes the value.

I realise this question is a bit vague but I can't provide the code as it's proprietary.

I've tried to break the problem down by setting a property manually within my widget as:

```
myProperty:0,
...
constructor
...
_setMyPropertyAttr: function(value):
{
    console.log("setting myproperty");
}

....
this.set('myProperty', 5);
....
```

but that isn't working either.

If you set a property within a widget does that not call the custom setter?

I'm struggling a bit because there aren't so many dojo examples out there any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In `this.set('myProperty', 5);` It depends on the context of this. Is the context referring to the correct widget?

Comment: this refers to the widget. When I drill into the _WidgetBase code, it tries to find the setter with the code this[names.s] where names.s = _setMyPropertyAttr. This suggests that my set and my handler are defined correctly but for some reason my widget doesn't contain the setter. I would have thought that perhaps the context of this was incorrect but it seems to have all the properties of the widget defined. To be clear I'm calling this.set('myProperty', 5) in an existing event handler in the code. When I call the same from startup it still doesn't work but does set the property value

Comment: What you share looks correct, so I bet the error is somewhere else. If the code is proprietary, can you try to make a minimal reproducible issue on jsfiddle ? So you wont share the original code and we will be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event to be called when a widget's property is set/update or you can even use `watch` to do that.
But this only works using the `set` function, using `someWidget.someProperty = 5;` wont work.
Let me show you how `dojo` do it. The basic about the magic setters and getters [is explained here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/understanding_widgetbase/index.html#getters-and-setters).

```
_set: function(/*String*/ name, /*anything*/ value){
    // summary:
    //      Helper function to set new value for specified property, and call handlers
    //      registered with watch() if the value has changed.
    var oldValue = this[name];
    this[name] = value;
    if(this._created && !isEqual(oldValue, value)){
        if(this._watchCallbacks){
            this._watchCallbacks(name, oldValue, value);
        }
        this.emit("attrmodified-" + name, {
            detail: {
                prevValue: oldValue,
                newValue: value
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This peace of code is from `dijit/_WidgetBase`, the `_set` function is what `dojo` calls after a `set` is called, and is where it finally set the property value `this[name] = value;` and as you can see, it `emit` an event that will be called `attrmodified-propertyName` and also call a `watchCallbacks`.

For example, if in some place, we have this:

```
on(someWidget, 'attrmodified-myproperty', function(){
    console.log(someWidget.get('myProperty'));
});
```

and then we use:

```
someWidget.set('myProperty', 'Hello World!');
```

The event will be triggered. Note that `someWidget.myProperty = 'Hello World!'` wont trigger the event registration. Also note that if in our widget we define the magic setter:

```
_setMyPropertyAttr: function(value) {
    //do something here with value
    // do more or less with other logic

    //but some where within this function we need to cal "_set"
    this._set('myProperty', value);
}
```

without calling `_set`, the magic wont happen.

As i said at the beginning, we can also use `watch`:

```
someWidget.watch('myProperty', function(){
    console.log(someWidget.get('myProperty'));
});
```

Note that we can register to this events or the `watch` function within the same widget.

Also, as a plus, the magic `setter` can be triggered when creating the widget with just passing the property name in the constructor object param, this work for the declarative syntax too, for example:

```
var someWidget = new MyWidget({
    'myProperty': 'Hello World!!'
});
```

and

```
<div data-dojo-type="MyWidget" data-dojo-props="myProperty: 'Hello World!!'"></div>
```

both will triggered a call to the `_setMyPropertyAttr` if exist, or dojo will use the magic `setter` in the case it doesn't exist.

Hope it helps

Comment: You've definatelt answered the set property part of my question. Turns out I was doing this.property=5 rather than using set('property',5); which triggers the setter. However do you know how I can hook into a change in the model my widget is bound to. For example if my model has property model.myproperty how can I handle a change in that property? I realise my question isn't very clear I will try and post a better example.

Comment: @msteel9999 do you mean by using `this.property=5` like `AngularJS` do? Using the `set` function isn't enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using custom setter on your widget, where you can add your custom logic.

Example of definition of custom setter on your widget:

```
     _setOpenAttr: function(/*Boolean*/ open){
         // execute some custom logic here
         this._set("open", open);
     }
```

Example of setting a property on your widget:

```
widgetRef.set('open', true);
```

Alternatively you can could consider using `dojo/store/Observable`.

`dojo/store/Observable` store wrapper that adds support for notification of data changes.

You can read more about it on the followign link:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Observable.html

Comment: :) BTW, there is no need for defining custom setter for setting a property named the same as the setter (like in your example). It's all automatic. `Observable` is always a good thing to use when using stores but i am not sure it will help in this case

Comment: @ben thanks for your comment, I made an edit to my answer, your are right but my idea was to add some custom logic within the setter :).

Answer (score 0):

If figured out the problem. If I set a watch on the model I can then check if indiviual properties have changed in the watch function. I knew it would be something simple!